# Access Kali VM IP from the hosting machine (macOS)

Tags: unix, virtualization, vmware

I have a Kali machine running in VMware on my Mac.

It has this IP : `172.16.155.128` as you can see.

[image]

I would like to access my Kali Linux IP from my host (macOS)

[image]

Do I need to add another network in VMware or restart some server?

This are the settings I have now. It's set to **NAT** already.

[image]

Comment: Can't you set it up to just be on the same subnet as everything else in the building? 172.16.. is a valid private address space, just not a common one like 192.168.. or 10...

Comment: I’ll try choosing NAT

Comment: @klanomath It looks like I configure to NAT already.

Comment: @klanomath I did a lot of testing through web interface. I start the service then I can go to the web portal to run a scan and export reports.

Comment: One of my PenTest tool. Arachni

Comment: OK do you have access now (from macOS)? Maybe some firewall is interfering?

Comment: I’m not in front of the computer at the moment. But I can grab and provide more screenshots. I have a lot of web testing tools and kind of need to access it from my host for a better user experience

Comment: OK, I think I got it: by default arachni_web is started with localhost:9292. localhost can't be accessed from remote. If you bind it to an IP or a hostname (e.g. `arachni_web -o 172.16.155.128` or `arachni_web -o kali.kyo.home` - the latter requires a running local DNS-server on your Mac with the zone kyo.home.), you can access the interface from your Mac (`172.16.155.128:9292`).